# Can't install plugin NPM

Tags: android, node.js, windows, cordova, npm

I have a cordova ionic application. I'm trying to install a plugin. I'm not able to. The error I have happens on any plugins I try to install really. It happens when I also try to delete a platform for example or run the application on Android. It just happens all the time. I can't figure out how to fix it. I've tried cleaning the cache, moving the cache location, running everything as administrator, giving full permission to my folder and all its children. I'm using Windows 10 as an administrator.

```
PS C:\Users\mario\Desktop\scmobileapppublic> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-file-transfer via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963248 Error output:
npm ERR! path C:\Users\mario\Desktop\scmobileapppublic\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\mario\Desktop\scmobileapppublic\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\mario\Desktop\scmobileapppublic\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\mario\\Desktop\\scmobileapppublic\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\aws4\\package.json\'\n    at Error (native)',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\mario\\Desktop\\scmobileapppublic\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\aws4\\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mario\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-31T21_18_02_104Z-debug.log
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know why, but those steps worked for me :

-> remove node_modules folder inside AppData/roaming/npm

-> open terminal as admin and do following cmd :

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Be in mind that will delete all your packages installed globally, Ionic and Cordova in our case.
So you'll need to reinstall them.

Comment: I have tried cleaning my cache many times but it didn't work. This time I did again but maybe removing node_modules folder inside AppData/roaming/npm did the trick. Now it works. I also deinstalled and reinstall node.js on top of that. Thank you sir.